# How do I access History state when navigating between 2 pages using pushstate?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, pushstate

I am working on my first PWA and currently doing a bit of research before I jump into writing any code. One thing that I can wrap my head around is the navigation between 2 cached pages.

My PWA consists of 2 pages page A which shows a list of items and page B which you navigate to when clicking an item on page A.

I was going to use history.pushstate to store the item id clicked on page A and then when page B is loaded it should ready the state and requested the required data based on what's in store.

I made a test page and I can see that adding `console.log('Hello Kitty')` to page B is triggered, so executing JS on page B should be simple. But when I try to read from history.state on page B, it's null.

My question is, how to I navigate between page A and B and read what I have stored in the history.state when page B is loaded?

I don't have any real code to show yet. And I plan on using web components but no framework or library of any kind, just vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use states for this. What about using a query component for page B (`B?id=<id>`), or storing the id on `localStorage`?

Comment: I dropped localStorage since it's not available to the service worker, at least that's what I've read so far. Using a querystring is an option, but it makes it difficult to cache the page since the ?id=<id> would be dynamic which means working offline is difficult

Comment: Makes sense... Well, I don't think there is a way to do that with history states, since you can't load another page with a state object. If you are using service workers to control fetching "offline first", you can return the same response and discard the query string.

Answer (score 0):

> I was going to use history.pushstate to store the item id clicked on page A and then when page B is loaded it should ready the state and requested the required data based on what's in store.

`history.pushState` wasn't made for storage. However, you *can* navigate from A to B with a custom state object with JavaScript:

In page A:

```js
history.pushState(obj, "", "B");
location.reload();
```

In page B:

```js
console.log(history.state); // Should log `obj`
```

You cannot "store" a state, navigate to B using a normal hyperlink and access the state, though. History states were made for navigating within a single-page web app without needing to load new pages. I would prefer to use a query string in the URL for B, in this case.

Comment: does not work for me. when i click page B, history is unset